# Search in mongo db by date

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a mongo db collection, where is row `createdDate`, which contains `datetime` value in format `Y-m-d H:i:s`. Is there any way to search through collection via method `find()` where I know only the date (`Y-m-d`)? I've tried few solutions, but nothing worked for me... Here is one of them. Thanks for any help!

```
$currentDate = '2017-05-16';
$dateQuery =  ['createdDate' => $currentDate];

foreach ($this->collection->find($dateQuery) as $key => $log) {
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved by myself:

```
    $dateRegex = new \MongoRegex(('/' . $currentDate . '/i'));

    foreach ($this->collection->find(['createdDate' => $dateRegex]) as $key => $log) {
        ....
    }
```